# Can someone please confirm that gets() is not part of the JavaScript Standard Library?

Tags: javascript, date

I recently worked my way through a developer pre-screen via an online candidate testing platform.  I've had bad experiences with these platforms in the past - poorly written/structured code, unclear instructions and code comments - but I'd yet to encounter a JavaScript question that (possibly) included C syntax ... until today.

The question was straightforward enough: create a `function` that took in a single parameter (`milliseconds`), converted that parameter to a new `Date` object and then returned only that `Date`'s day-of-the-month.

Here was the boilerplate code I was asked to start with:

```
function convertMilliseconds(milliseconds) {
   var result = -404;
   return result;
}

var milliseconds = Number(gets());

console.log(convertMilliseconds(milliseconds));
```

*Edit*: To clarify, `gets()` was not explicitly referenced in the question's prompt, nor were there are any code comments in the web-based code editor asking me to implement it as a custom function.  Here is a screen cap to illustrate:

[image]

**Can someone please confirm for me that `gets()` is *not* part of the JavaScript Standard Library?**

I've consulted the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) and did not find anything in the entry for `Number` to indicate this was valid code.  I did, however, find references to [C library function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_gets.htm) called `gets()`.

I try and make a point of using these pre-screens to fill any conspicuous gaps in my JavaScript knowledge.  I'm pretty sure this is just a glaring error on the testing platform's part; I just want to be doubly sure I'm right before writing this off and moving onto other things.

Comment: `gets()` isn't a standard function.  What is it?

Comment: What lead you to believe think a function from a C library would work in Javascript? They are entirely different languages and environments. Are you asking if `gets()` makes sense, or are you asking how to convert a string to a number? Also, depending on the interview, `gets()` might be implemented in Javascript to capture user input, in part of the code you're not showing us. The code is 100% valid assuming `gets()` is defined. Maybe you didn't read the screening instructions properly?

Comment: To me, `gets` sounds like get seconds.  So I'd imagine it was a function that returned some number of seconds.  But it would need to be included in the code sample because it doesn't exist in Javascript by itself.

Comment: I apologize if I was unclear.  I was not under the impression that a C library function would work in JavaScript!  I'm trying to confirm my hunch that the question provided by this testing platform was poorly written (i.e. someone didn't properly convert a similar C-focused question into valid JavaScript).

Comment: It could be that `gets()` is defined for the test specifically. There is not much reason to believe it isn't the case. Not with the (lack of) information supplied here. So, no - it's not standard in JS. That doesn't necessarily mean it doesn't work, though.

Comment: `Number(gets())` is a valid JavaScript if `gets` is a function btw. Just saying if it has not been made clear already.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski "*Number(gets()) is a valid JavaScript if gets is a function*" it's valid JavaScript regardless. Whether or not *it works* is another matter. `x = null; x.toLowerCase()` is also *valid* JavaScript that *leads to an error*. The language rules do allow both constructs.

Comment: It can be that `gets` is provided by the environment for convenience

Comment: As always, I appreciate everyone's feedback, most especially the feedback drawing my attention to the imprecise and ambiguous wording of my initial question.  I have edited my original post to: (1) better reflect my original intent and (2) include a screencap of the boilerplate code provided by the testing platform.

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting as an answer. JavaScript does not have a `gets()` so if it executes it is some method that they added to their test framework to get test data.

Comment: What happens if you log `milliseconds` and hit "Compile & Run"? Does it print something? Does it throw an error because `gets` is not provided?

Comment: @epascarello Just wanted to confirm that, given the boilerplate code provided, `gets()` wasn't something that would have run without errors right out of the box.

Comment: "*Just wanted to confirm that, given the boilerplate code provided, gets() wasn't something that would have run without errors right out of the box*" we cannot confirm that. We can only say that `gets()` is not a standard JS function. That does *not* mean it doesn't work in the challenge where it was provided. It might, if it's supplied by the environment there. Challenge sites often do have extra code not immediately visible. It will not work if it's indeed an error as you suspect and/or a custom `gets()` is not supplied by the environment.

Comment: @VLAZ I no longer have access to the test platform, so I'm afraid I can't answer that question.  Given everyone's comments, I suspect that either (1) this was a poorly written test question or (2) as @KonradLinkowski suggested `gets()` was provided by the testing environment for convenience and its inclusion (without comment) simply threw me.  While creating `function convert(milliseconds)` I rewrote the code such that `milliseconds = 1613132555000` (the "sample input" referenced in the prompt).